# Corrupt png or jpeg image files when stored in bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, binary-data

I am trying to write an httpserver using netcat. It doesn't work I dont know why ? when I remove ' read -s GET ', it works for plain text but for images it doesn't, the browser displays only the icon for broken images.

```
nc -l -k -p 80 -q 1 -e serverhttp.sh
```

*serverhttp.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

index_page=index.html
error_page=Error.html

read -s GET # it doesn't work with this commond to be able to detect path.
resource=$(echo "$input" | grep -P -o '(?<=GET \/).*(?=\ )')
[ -z "$resource" ] && resource=$index_page || resource=$error_page

content_type=$(file -b --mime-type $resource)

case "$(echo "$content_type" | cut -d '/' -f2)" in
html)
    output=$(cat "$resource")
;;

jpeg)
    output=$(cat "$resource")
;;

png)
    output=$(cat "$resource")
;;

*)
    echo 'Unknown type'
esac

content_length=$(stat -c '%s' $resource)
echo -ne "HTTP 200 OK\r\n"
echo -ne "Content-Length: $content_length\r\n"
echo -ne "Content-Type: $content_type\r\n\n$output\n"
```

Comment: As always with bash scripts, start by running it through https://shellcheck.net and fixing the issues it points out.

Comment: @joan - _specifically_ the reason it doesn't work is that shell variables are C strings. C uses NUL-delimited strings; but in this case your binary data can contain NULs inside the file. That means the shell needs to either end the input at the first NUL, or just take all the NULs out; either of those corrupts a file that's expected to be byte-for-byte perfect.

Comment: ...now, it _is_ possible to store binary data in shell variables, but those variables can't be strings; instead, they need to be arrays, where every NUL becomes the boundary between two array elements.

Comment: I'd show how to do this if we had a simpler question narrowly focused on it, but there's a bunch of unrelated how-do-I-do-HTTP content in here that muddles the question a lot.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy something like `mapfile -d '' bin_data <image.gif` to read the data. Then `{ printf '%s' "${bin_data[0]}"; printf '\0%s' "${bin_data[@]:1}";} >copy_of_image.gif"` to output the binary data from the variable?

Comment: @LéaGris, yup, that's very much the kind of thing I meant to advocate. (I've usually put special-case handling at the end instead of the front, appending an extra empty string iif the buffer has a trailing NUL, but your way is easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it does not work with image files is because these are binary data and the Shell cannot store binary into variables like here:

```sh
output=$(cat "$resource")
```

Also as stated by [Shawn, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951773/bash-netcat-as-httpserver-including-resources-of-the-html-page#comment118345806_66951773) there are code pitfalls that would be shown to you with a code check from https://shellcheck.net/

Here is how you could deal with binary files:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Function to stream a binary file as HTTP body
send_body () {
  printf '\r\n'
  cat "$1" 2>/dev/null || : # Can stream binary data
  printf '\r\n'
}

input=$1

index_page=index.html
error_page=Error.html

# Parses the request string with Bash's built-in Regex engine
[[ "$input" =~ ^GET[[:space:]]/(.*)/?[[:space:]]HTTP/1\.[01]?$ ]] || :
resource=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

# When resource is empty, substitute the value of $index_page
resource=${resource:-$index_page}

# Capture mime type
content_type=$(file -b --mime-type "$resource")

# Set http status code depending on if resource file exist
if [ -f "$resource" ]; then
  http_status='200 OK'
else
  resource="$error_page"
  content_type='text/html'
  http_status='404 NOT FOUND'
fi

# Check supported MIME types
case "${content_type#*/}" in
  html | jpeg | png) ;;
  *)
    printf '%s\n' 'Unknown type' >&2
    resource="$error_page"
    content_type='text/html'
    http_status='415 UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE'
    ;;
esac

# Capture the content_length (default to 0)
read -r content_length _ < <(wc -c "$resource" 2>/dev/null)
content_length=${content_length:-0}

# Send reply
printf 'HTTP %s\r\n' "$http_status"
printf 'Content-Length: %d\r\n' "$content_length"
printf 'Content-Type: %s\r\n' "$content_type"
send_body "$resource"
```

Comment: @joan sure it does not work, it cannot and this is exactly what I say in my answer: `Shell cannot store binary into variables`